# How to save and resume the state of a Racket sandboxed evaluator?

Tags: scheme, racket

Racket provides facilities for creating [sandboxed evaluators](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Sandboxed_Evaluation.html). Suppose I have a sandboxed evaluator, how can I save its state into a file (e.g. `(save-evaluator my-evaluator "my-evaluator.save")`, switch off my computer, come back the next day, and load the evaluator so that I get to resume from where I left off?

I looked at `racket/serialize`, but sandboxed evaluators are not serializable objects. The other solution I can think of is to somehow save the "environment" (i.e. variable and procedure bindings), and somehow load them into a new evaluator when I am ready to resume.

Any solutions or pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is...you can't.

The evaluator state of a sandbox contains too much information to serialize, without basically capturing a snapshot of your entire OS.

So, while you *could* evaluate your program in a virtual machine, and use its save mechanism, I suspect this is overkill for what you actually want. As such, there are probably solutions that get close to what you are looking for.

One of the simplest one is the web server's [serializable continuations](http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server/stateless.html?q=web-server%2Flang%2Fabort-resume#%28mod-path._web-server%2Flang%2Fabort-resume%29). These basically work by limiting you to a subset of Racket that can actually be serialized.

Another (more manual) option is to handle the serialization yourself. Obviously this is more work, but gives you significantly more control on what you want to serialize. Note though that you will only be able to store an environment, and not a (possibly local) continuation. The way I would go about that is to get your sandbox's namespace, and use this to get its corresponding environment with [`namespace-mapped-symbols`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Namespaces.html?q=namespace-%3E#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._namespace-symbol-~3eidentifier%29%29). You can then use the `racket/serialize` library to serialize each value in that environment.